# is TransactionScope usable for sql operations, is it doing the same thing as Sqltransaction?

Tags: c#, sql, transactionscope

can I do something like this:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Cs))
                {
                    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                       ...
                        scope.complete();

                    }
                }
            }
```

is going to be the same thing as using the SqlTransaction with `catch(){rollback;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TransactionScope creates an `implicit transaction`, therefore any action within the transaction scope that supports transactional processing, will be handled by their according Transaction Manager.

In the case of database processing, it will use `SqlTransaction`. So yes, your given code will do the same as doing it by hand using the SqlTransaction.

---

You can call `transaction.Current` to get a handler to the current transaction manager to ensure this.

Note that one `TransactionScope` object can have óne implicit transaction type, so you will need to nest `TransactionScope` objects to ensure transactional processing over multiple managers. F.e.:

```
using(var ts = new TransactionScope)
{
      using(var db = new TransactionScope)
      {
         //do db processing
      }
      using(var msmq = new TransactionScope)
      {
         //do msmq processing
      }
      ts.Complete();
}
```